# Creating two std::vector objects inside of function and returning both by reference

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

Using C++, I would like to create an instance of a vector object `input`, as shown in the `main()` function of the test program below.  The `input` vector is filled with data, and then passed by reference to a `compute()` function.  The compute function is to return two vector objects `real` and `imag`.

Is it possible to return these two vector objects in the manner shown in the code snippet below?

Compiling this code using `gcc` gives the following errors:

```
In function ‘void compute(const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&)’:
error: declaration of ‘std::vector<double> real’ shadows a parameter
error: declaration of ‘std::vector<double> imag’ shadows a parameter
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this?  Here is the complete test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void compute(const std::vector<double> &input,
                    std::vector<double> &real, std::vector<double> &imag)
{
        unsigned int N = input.size();
        unsigned int csize = (N / 2) + 1;

        // the error occurs here
        std::vector<double> real(csize);
        std::vector<double> imag(csize);

        for (int i = 0; i < csize; i++)
        {
            real[i] = input[i] * i;
            imag[i] = input[i] * -i;
        }
 } // end


int main()
{
    const int num = 10;
    std::vector<double> input(num);
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        input[i] = i;

    std::vector<double> real;
    std::vector<double> imag;

    compute(input, real, imag);

 } // end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vectors already exist and so you don't want to create them again, instead resize them to be the proper size:

```
real.resize(csize);
imag.resize(csize);
```

Your code was actually valid, but since you're compiling on -Werror it's rejected. By "shadowing" it means that you would be creating and modifying vectors local to the function and so the ones passed by reference wouldn't have been updated.

Comment: Thanks Pubby!  Just out of curiosity, is the `resize()` done in an efficient manner?  Or would it be better to simply set the size of the vector when the instance is created?

Comment: @NicholasKinar It may involve an unnecessary memcpy but it's not a huge problem. I would change the function to use iterators which has the benefit of being more general and better performance.

Comment: So rather than using a `for` loop, an iterator would be used?  The use of an iterator still does not eliminate the need for a resize?

Comment: No, the use of an iterator is only for iterating through the vector.  A resize is still needed before use of the iterator.

Comment: @NicholasKinar For clarification, you wouldn't resize the vector inside the function. The vector would be resized before or use a back_inserter iterator.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that, Pubby.  The back_inserter would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change "compute" to:

```
void compute(const std::vector<double> &input,
                std::vector<double> &real, std::vector<double> &imag)
{
    unsigned int N = input.size();
    unsigned int csize = (N / 2) + 1;

    real.resize(csize);
    imag.resize(csize);

    for (int i = 0; i < csize; i++)
    {
        real[i] = input[i] * i;
        imag[i] = input[i] * -i;
    }
} // end
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good answer as well, and shows where the resize should be done in the code.